# Akka: how to manage a double http request?

Tags: scala, akka

In my actor I have two requests at different addresses like this:

```
http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = encodedUri).addHeader(Accept(MediaTypes.`application/json`)))
```

I need that these two requests return both a value. As normal futures I would expect something like this:

```
val response: Future[SomeData] = for {
        r1 <- firstRequest
        r2 <- secondRequest
      } yield {
        // merge the results of these two responses
      }

      response onComplete {
        case Success(body) => sndr ! Something(body)
        case Failure(message) => BadRequest(message.toString)
      }
```

In this part of the documentation:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html

It is suggested to use `pipeTo` to `self` to manage the single request, instead of using native `onComplete/map/etc`.

How can I apply that for multiple requests like in my case, where I need to wait for 2 or more to be completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple and straight foward**

```
val f1 = Future { //request1 }

val f2 = Future { //request2 }

val resultF = f1 zip f2 

resultF pipeTo self
```

Current actor will get the result as a message and message will be a tuple `(f1Result, f2Result)`

if result `resultF` fails current actor gets failure message wrapped in `akka.actor.Status.Failure`

In the method `f1` and `f2` are independent futures

In case `f2` depends on the value of `f1` use `flatMap`

```
 val resultF = f1.flatMap { f1Result => createF2(f1Result) }

 //alternatively we can use for comprehension

 resultF pipeTo self
```

**Example**

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Status.Failure

import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.pattern.pipe

object ManagerActor {
  case object Exec
}

class ManagerActor extends Actor {

  import ManagerActor._

  implicit val dispather = context.dispatcher

 override def receive: Receive = {
    case Exec =>

    val f1 = Future { 1 }

    val f2 = Future { 2 }

    val resultF = f1 zip f2

    resultF pipeTo self

   case result: (Int, Int) => //be careful about type erasure 
     println(s"""result:$result""")

   case Failure(th) =>
     println(s"""msg: ${th.getMessage}""")

   }
}
```

to run

```
object Main {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val system = ActorSystem()
   val actor = system.actorOf(Props[ManagerActor])
   actor ! ManagerActor.Exec
   Thread.sleep(1000000)
 }
}
```

We can use `Future.sequence` instead to `zip` to generalise this to any number of http requests.

Comment: `flatMap` could be not good as `map`. I think the real problem is the visibility of the sender inside the future threads.